# How can I configure a virtual host on Apache?

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox, apache2

I am trying to create a virtual host on `Apache` in `Ubuntu`(in a virtual machine) but I cannot get it. I did a lot of configurations but any of them give me any result so I created a new virtual machine to do it from the begining. I am going to put here all the process step by step so all of you could follow what I am doing wrong.

### What I have

- VirtualBox
- Ubuntu 14.04 (Virtual machine on VirtualBox)
- I instaled Apache on Ubuntu (`sudo apt-get install apache2`)

### What I need

- When I write the url `ejemplo.es` on my browser the file that I created on my `VirtualHost` folder will be displayed and not the page that it is on `www.ejemplo.es` (that it is not mine).
- Use `hosts` file on `/etc` folder instead of DNS configuration.

### What I tried

- **First of all: change the root directory of my server**

First of all, what I need it is to make my root directory of my server as `/var/www/extras` so I created this new directory on `/var/www`.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/extras
```

and create an `index.html` with some text on it.

After creating the new directory I have to change my `000-default.conf` file to change the `DocumentRoot` directive.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and change the `DocumentRoot` directive as follows:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/extras
```

and after that I restart `Apache` to save my changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and modify the `Directory` block on `apache2.conf` file

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

from `<Directory /var/www/html>` to `<Directory /var/www/extras>` and restart `Apache` again.

- **Second step: creating the folder and the file from the virtual host I want to create**

Inside `/var/www/extras` directory I am going to create a new folder (`ejemplo.es`) which is going to be the folder of my virtual host.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/extras/ejemplo.es
```

and inside of it an `index.html` file as I created for the root directory of my server with the text `"This is an example"`.

After that, if I go to the browser and write `localhost/ejemplo.es` I can see the content of the file I created in the step before. **But what I want it is to access to the same content but typing `ejemplo.es` instead of `localhost/ejemplo.es`**.

- **Final step: Configurate the virtual host**

I need to create a new file on `/etc/apache2/sites-available` with the configuration of my virtual host.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/ejemplo.es.conf
```

with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.2.15:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ejemplo.es
    ServerName ejemplo.es
    ServerAlias www.ejemplo.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/extras/ejemplo.es
</VirtualHost>
```

and on `apache2.conf` file I am going to change `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` to `Include sites-enabled/*.conf`. (This was a prove to see if maybe my `Apache` did not include this folder and could be the posibility that my `VirtualHost` did not work for that).

So now I have to activate the VirtualHost I have created:

```
sudo a2ensite ejemplo.es
```

and restart `Apache` to save the changes I made:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If I list the content of the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` I can see that my `VirtualHost` it is active now (`ls` command to this folder).

To end, I add a new line on my hosts file (`sudo gedit /etc/hosts`):

```
10.0.2.15   ejemplo.es
```

so now the file has three lines with IP's:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    user
10.0.2.15    ejemplo.es
```

and some lines below that starts with `ff00...` but I think they are not relevant for my purpose.

And finally I have to execute the following command to save my last changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

but I get the default page of `www.ejemplo.es` instead the file that I put on my `VirtualHost` folder.

I am sure I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out where. It is the first time I create one `VirtualHost` and all tutorials that I have seen had these steps so I think I am missing something.

I expect you could follow my steps and ask if you have some doubt about the configuration that I made.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must note that /etc/hosts only work with explicit ip>host  directives, that means that subdomains wildcard do not apply. So 'ejemplo.es' is diffrent than 'www.ejemplo.es', so add the later with the same ip to the file and see if it works. Check https://serverfault.com/questions/118378/in-my-etc-hosts-file-on-linux-osx-how-do-i-do-a-wildcard-subdomain if you need wildcard support.

Comment: @bistoco but my `ServerName` of my VirtualHost is `ejemplo.es`, `www.ejemplo.es` it is the `ServerAlias`.

Comment: Yes, but you need to point `www.ejemplo.es` to your vm, adding the line `10.0.2.15    www.ejemplo.es` on `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on the question for further information but I haven't had enough reputation point, so I just try answer this for you to give us little more information.

I did the same steps as you listed above in my new VM, and it's work fine.

I don't know exactly how you test the above domain, whether browser in your box (ubuntu - client) or in your host (which is running virtualbox).

If you're trying to visit the domain under client-ubuntu, you can add more IP into virtualhost tag:

```
<VirtualHost ejemplo.es:80 127.0.1.100:80 192.168.1.100:80></VirtualHost>.
```

Here 127.0.1.100 and 192.168.1.100 are example IPs that all pointing to ejemplo.es.

If you're trying to access from your host with IP 10.0.x.x, it may be not accessible. Especially if you didn't select the right network type for your VM. You can ping the IP first before checking the local domain work. In my case, I select the bridge connection (with copied NAT), so my VM can act just like any other physical device in my network.

Other thing is, if you have your site which is already on-service, and you want a local environment for developing and testing, it's better to use different domain (such as: .local, .dev) instead of using same domain.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answer! Now, by parts: 1.- Did you do exactly the same steps as me? Do you get the `index.html` content when you put `ejemplo.es` in your browser instead of another page (the real on-service page (I know that it is used but I just wanted to make some proves on my local environment)? 2.- I am trying to test the VirtualHost on my Ubuntu client, not in my host. 3.- I do not know what do you mean with `virtualhost tag` and what to do with the IPS that you  put there in that paragraph.

Comment: 4.- I am trying to access with the IP 10.0.2.15 as you can see above which is the IP of my Ubuntu client (If I use the command `ifconfig`) and the network of my VM is NAT (I do not know if it is a correct mode or not). 5.- In this step, do you mean ping to the IP 10.0.2.15 before trying the local domain works? 6.- No, as I put on my other comment, this is not my site, it is just a domain that I want to use on my local environment.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly same steps as you did. I can see the content of index.html.

Comment: The differences here are the network type and IPs. I can use the bound IP to visit the website in host or client. And like @bistoco commented above, you also need to added www.< domain >.es in the hosts file, if you really want to visit your site with www suffix. And sorry for not editing my answer in time, the editor was kind of cutting off that part.

Answer (score -1):

Well kind of unclear without seeing all the configs but few things I can say

1. First check that NamedVirtualHosting is uncommented in the ports.conf file
2. change the permissions just to be sure under the `/var/www/`

   `sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/*`
3. check if the syntax of the symbolic link in sites-enabled folder is correct or if the symbolic link is broken *broken links shows in red*
   the syntax goes like this **000-default** and whatever comes next goes like **001-test** or **002-guest**
   check by

   `ll /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*`

Check if the syntax of the `ejemplo.es.conf` is correct

It looks like this. Make sure the directory is mentioned

[image]

I hope this helps good luck